# How to post correctly fields in views-view-fields.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm using Drupal 7, and [Views 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I would like to reproduce my comment template in `views-view-fields.tpl.php`.

Thus I need to print my fields to be able to arrange them as I wish it.

For each field, I proceed like that : `<?php print $view->render_field('field_name', $id);?>`, is it the correct/secure way ?

I don't think so, because all the row does not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is:

```
<?php print $fields["field_name"]->content; ?>
```

---

**Note:** Using `views-view-fields.tpl.php` will affect all of your views, which you may not want.

To target a specific view you need to use:

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).tpl.php**

Comment: It works, but I have now for every field an error of type: `Notice : Trying to get property of non-object dans include()` and `Notice : Undefined index: namefield dans include()` Do you know where from it can come?

Comment: Did you name your template like this `views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine-name].tpl.php` ?

Comment: Yes. I think that this problem appears when I disconnect. Fields indeed appear only when the users are connected. I would have to include in the views template a condition of type "if" i think

Comment: But I do not know the syntax. I try this `<?php if ($fields["field_name"]->content;): ?>` but it does not work

Comment: Are you trying to check if it exists? You don't need the `;` inside the bracket, if it still does not work after deleting the `;` try `<?php if (isset($fields["field_name"]->content)): ?>` something goes here `<?php endif; ?>`